# Lookup on data extension on sendable email

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

So I am trying to get the row of a data extension, but I need to be able to search by two columns, in my case language and brand

I have this right now:

```
%%[SET @test = Lookup("dataext","Name","language ", "EN")]%%
```

I have tried this:

```
%%[SET @test = ExecuteFilter("dataext", "Language", "EN", "Brand", "sony")]%%
```

but this gives me the following error:

> ExecuteFilter Function is not valid in content. This function is only
>   allowed in non sendable content.

Is there a way to do a  lookup, on a DE filtering by more than one column?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup is an overloaded method, so you can keep adding "column", "value" as many times as you like at the end, essentially building the WHERE clause.  I've done this:

```
  %%[
  SET @testVal = LOOKUP("DEForStateVariationsContent","StateCode","StateCode", "StateCode, "AdditionalVal", "Ad")
 ]%%
```

In your case - you would use-

```
%%[SET @test = Lookup("dataext","Name","language ", "EN","Brand", "sony")]%%
```

Comment: Here are a couple of other examples: http://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/